# How to post textbox array name value using xmlhttp

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am a newbie programmer. Is their a way I can post the array name in php file using `xmlhttp`.I have seen same question like this but it was totally advance with my basic information.

Here's my sample code problem:

HTML

```
<body>
  <input type="text" id="department" name="department[]" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="department1" name="department[]" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="output" name="output" style="width:100%; height:200px;" />
  <br />
  <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="submit" onClick="showvalue()" />
</body>
```

JS

```
 function showvalue() {
   var dept=document.getElementsByName("department[]").value;


   var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {     
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)     {       
       document.getElementById("output").value=xmlhttp.responseText;    
   }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("POST","processbranch.php",true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send("&dept1="+dept); 

 }
```

PHP

```
$dept = $_POST['dept1'];
foreach($dept as $key => $deptval)
{
  echo $deptval;
}
```

Please give me some sample like my code. Please sir/mam. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: What's the error in your code?

Comment: in that sample.. i just want to know sir how i can post the textbox array name in php using ajax xmlhttp

Comment: var dept=document.getElementsByName("department[]").value;

How i can post all the value inside the department[] in php file.... using this

xmlhttp.open("POST","processbranch.php",true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send("&dept1="+dept); 


sir sorry if my english is too bad..... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

hey @shiro Jacinto just change the name of your input department[dept] & department[dept1] in both the input. But I tell you its not a proper way. you can follow the steps

1) create a simple form with different name.
2) call js function on submit.
3) create json object and add your fields into it.
4) post your data to desired php file using jQuery post or ajax post.

Try using this [link](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). Hope this will help you

Comment: why suggesting him to use jquery when he is doing in js ?

Comment: sir I must not change the name the textbox because i will using foreach to get the department[0],department[1],department[2].... so on...

In html->php.. the textbox name department[] post using form action method post.. just $_POST['department']; using foreach i can gather the file inside sir... how i can do it like that using the script... sorry if my english is bad

Comment: im sorry sir if im so noob... can i beg some site basic sample like that... posting the deparment[] in php file with js

Comment: ok, try to push your data into another array var simArr = [];and in your loop  push into that arrat i.e. simArr.push('your val'); then stringify that array using var stringed = JSON.stringify(simArr ); and afterwards assign this stringify data to your department var and post into php file and decode it into there :).

Comment: sir can you help me how to decode or get only the value with this output ing php... department%5B%5D=Roar&department%5B%5D=Jacinto.. i just try ajax then the output was that... the value their are department[0] = Roar and department[1] = Jacinto..... sorry sir.. if my english is too bad :(

Comment: Its ok no problem with that, your data is encoded convert it using this then you will get the proper values $str = 'department%5B%5D=Roar&department%5B%5D=Jacinto';
var_dump(urldecode($str )); hope this will help you.